# Catch Segmentation fault in c++

Tags: c++, crash, segmentation-fault

Does a `try-catch` block catch segmentation fault errors?

I am reading a text file using the function given below but sometimes the file is empty and the program crashes. I would like the program to continue running and provide another file when this file is empty or in use.

```
Path2D read_gesture(const char* filename)
{
    Path2D path;
    //MultiStrokeGesture MultiStrokes;

    vector<string> text_file;

    int no_of_paths=0;
    std::ifstream ifs(filename);

    for (std::string line; std::getline(ifs, line); )
    {
        no_of_paths=no_of_paths+1;
        double a, b;
        stringstream ss(line);
        if (!(ss >> a >> b)) {cout<<"wrong format"<<endl;}
        std::cout << "You said, " << a << ", " << b << ".\n";
        path.push_back(Point2D(a,b));

    }
    cout<<"saving gesture"<<endl;
    return path;


}
```

I tried something like:

```
Path2D path;
try 
{
    path=read_gesture("test.txt");
}
catch(int e)
{
    path=read_gesture("test2.txt");
}
```

but the program still crashes. What might the problem be?

- A little correction, the file called in `catch` was not same as that of `try`, that was a typo.

Comment: It makes no sense to ask "how to prevent a crash". The only answer is "write a correct program".

Comment: `catch(int e)` does not catch c++ exceptions like `std::exception`, it catches an integer

Comment: You should fix the source of your exception, not try to catch it. If you have a segmentation fault in your program, you're the most likely cause. (Not trying to be mean to you, just that's the most likely cause. :)  )

Comment: if `read_gesture` may generate an exception and is in the catch block, you should have another try-catch block there as well, and so on recursively... try doing something different (that doesn't generates exceptions!)

Comment: You're calling the same code in your `try` and `catch` blocks. If you did catch an exception, that tells you that something went **Badly wrong** so the *very last* thing you should do is do the same thing again. Exception handling is about retaining control and either correcting the issue or exiting gracefully. That's the definition of insanity: doing the same thing over and over again and expecting different results.

Comment: @Component10: I thought it was standard behavior in trying to reproduce bugs!

Comment: @KerrekSB the program is correct , the problem is with the text file i am reading .That's why i have prevent the crash .

Comment: @rajat: If your program crashes because of "bad input", then your program isn't correct.

Comment: @KerrekSB That was my question , how to correct my program for bad input . duhh .

Comment: Well, for starters, you need to put `continue;` into the error branch of the `<<` operation...

Comment: @rajat You accepted an incorrect answer - [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12978234/how-to-prevent-crash-in-c/12978275#comment26587613_12978392)

Comment: It must have been by mistake, or by default. I have changed the answer.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

C++ `try-catch` blocks only handle C++ exceptions. Errors like segmentation faults are lower-level, and try-catch ignores these events and behaves the same as if there was no try-catch block.

Comment: Also if you compile with /EHs option?

Answer (score 16):

try/catch only catches C++ exceptions. Segmentation faults will only occur when your program does something illegal and invokes undefined behavior.

Remember that undefined behavior can manifest in different ways, including not crashing. You're lucky to have your program to crash to inform you that there's something you need to fix, but the program may not crash; you can't make your fallback code depend on the crash.

The appropriate thing to do is not to handle the crash like you would an exception, but instead to ensure that your program does not do anything illegal even when the input is not what you expect. In this case you need to change your code so that you know when the file is empty and need to provide another one.

---

There usually is a way to handle segmentation faults, but it's not intended to do the kind of recovery you're looking for. The mechanism is signals. You can install a signal handler which executes when a specified signal is raised, such as SIGSEGV for segmentation faults. However there's no requirement that such a signal will actually occur except when you explicitly raise it with std::raise. Also the things you can do in a signal handler when the signal is raised by the implementation are severely restricted;

> If the signal occurs other than as the result of calling the abort or
>   raise function, the behavior is undefined if the signal handler refers
>   to any object with static storage duration other than by assigning a
>   value to an object declared as volatile sig_atomic_t, or the signal
>   handler calls any function in the standard library other than the
>   abort function, the _Exit function, or the signal function with the
>   first argument equal to the signal number corresponding to the signal
>   that caused the invocation of the handler. Furthermore, if such a call
>   to the signal function results in a SIG_ERR return, the value of errno
>   is indeterminate.

Comment: exacly, simplifing "tl;dr be happy that your code seg fault as this prevents more potential damage, you cannot work with undefined behaviour. Thats not how it works."
Im just going to add something from self - trying to use simplest possible language - processor will interpret every piece of data as command, so if you seg fail, your processor may get random trash from memory but not what you wanted and this will cause it to do some random things, including messing with other programs and OS. this is why seg fault is triggered (hopefully) every time you try doing this. To prevent damage.

Answer (score 8):

If your program has a segmentation fault, and it's not something you did on purpose, then there's nothing you can do about it.  You can't catch it, and even if you could, you can't continue the program afterwards.

Furthermore, the following code has a very serious problem:

```
try {
    path=read_gesture("test.txt");
}
catch(int e) {
    path=read_gesture("test.txt");
}
```

"If at first you don't succeed, try again" is a good motto for humans, but computers do things the exact same way every time.  If an operation fails, unless it's a transient failure (such as a network failure), trying again is futile.

Your only choice is to write a *correct program,* because correct programs do not segfault.  If you want to find the segfault, you can run the program in Valgrind or GDB, both of which should give backtraces full of clues (but you have to use your head to find the true error in your program).

The other alternative is to use a language which does not get segfaults, like Java, C#, Python, Ruby, Haskell, JavaScript, Go, Rust, or almost every language used these days except C or C++.

**Footnote:** This is a bit of a simplification, since it is actually possible to write correct programs that get segmentation faults.  However, that's not what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to add a little test to see if ifs is valid:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
   std::ifstream ifs( "notExists" );
   if( ifs.is_open()) {
      char line[1024];
      while(! ifs.fail() && ifs.getline( line, sizeof( line ))) {
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
      }
   }
   else {
      std::cout << "file doesn't exists." << std::endl;
   }
   std::cout << "done." << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This program runs and output:

```
file doesn't exists.
done.
```

[bool std::ifstream::is_open();](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ifstream/is_open/)

See the [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/) global function for more information, if it fail, it set some bit not checked here.

Errors are signaled by modifying the internal state flags:

- eofbit: The end of the source of characters is reached during its operations.
- failbit: No characters were extracted because the end was prematurely found.Notice that some eofbit cases will also set failbit.
- badbit: An error other than the above happened.

Additionally, in any of these cases, if the appropriate flag has been set with is's member function ios::exceptions, an exception of type ios_base::failure is thrown.

Comment: What's the point -- that added condition has absolutely no effect.

Comment: Because the `getline` will fail anyway if the stream isn't good, and it'll return the stream object which evaluates as `false` in the test. So, no need. At best you could add an `if (!ifs)` at the beginning of the program to produce a meaningful error message.

Comment: And when it fail it set a bit not checked here

Comment: Can you please describe a scenario in which your code would behave differently from the simpler one without the additional check? With example, if possible.

Comment: Yes: when the file doesn't exists

Comment: That's not true. The simpler program will work just as well. Please provide a tested example.

Comment: Sample modified. It's my last comment.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can(read should) write your code in a way that it never generate exceptions such as segmentation fault.

First you should check all pointers that may be invalid(for example a public function of your class that will be called by the user of the class may receive some invalid pointer but internal implementation may assume the pointer already checked).

Second you should check result of functions that may fail, for example `malloc` may fail to allocate memory or a file that you try to open may be deleted or you do not have permission to open it or even after opening it its data may be invalid, so you should check result of your action. This process in C++ is much easier than C, for example `new` throw an exception on failure or `stream` will be convertible to `false` in case of any error or eof.

But to answer your question generally `catch` block only catch typed exceptions but in some compilers `catch(...)` may also catch exceptions like segmentation fault or even convert those exceptions to a C++ exception, for example under windows platform you may use `_set_se_translator` to set a global translator for exceptions like that to C++ exceptions and with MSVC you can also compile your program with `/EHa` to enable it catch those kind of exceptions in `catch(...)` but all of this are extensions that are specific to specific platform or compiler thus write your code correctly and never think of such a way to solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

try to check is it catcheable with `catch(...){cout<<'catched';}`

Also try this line, this way you prevent pushing wrong format points:

`if (!(ss >> a >> b)) {cout<<"wrong format"<<endl; continue;}`

Comment: You should never use catch-all clause without re-throw.

Comment: Why is this answer accepted? It is incorrect in more than one way: (1) even catch(...) won't catch low-level faults; (2) syntactically, 'catched' is illegal. Look to H2CO3's answer.

Comment: @OldPeculier About (1) You are completely right; about (2) Though you are also right, remember a lot of us are not native English speakers (me included, obviously).

Comment: @ebasconp What are you talking about? @OldPeculier meant with (2) that `'catched'` is not syntactically correct in C++ (single quotes don't make strings), not in English